# Can't import Let's Encrypt certificate to Amazon Certificate Manager

Tags: certificate, amazon-web-services, letsencrypt

I have been using `certbot` to renew my Let's Encrypt certificate every 2.5 months and import it to Amazon Certificate Manager manually through the AWS console to use with cloudfront. The command I use is

```
certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges=dns
```

The process has been going fine for more than a year. However during the last renew, after I had reimported the certificate into ACM, the console showed no certificate and my certificate seemed to disappear. When I imported that certificate again as a new one, it disappeared as well.
I tried with AWS CLI instead, and `aws acm list-certificates` found both certificates. But I have trouble with `describe-certificate` and `import-certificate`:

```
aws acm --region=us-east-1 import-certificate --certificate fileb://cert.pem --certificate-chain fileb://fullchain.pem --private-key fileb://privkey.pem --certificate-arn <my-certificate-arn>

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the ImportCertificate operation: Could not validate the certificate with the certificate chain.
```

```
aws acm --region=us-east-1 describe-certificate --certificate-arn <my-certificate-arn>

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the DescribeCertificate operation: Could not validate the certificate with the certificate chain.
```

The problem is, despite the fact that ACM could not verify the certificate, my original certificate that was reimported through the console was still used by Cloudfront, and Firefox is showing my website with the new certificate as normal. The question is, is there anything changed in either ACM or Let's Encrypt? As far that I can tell, the certificate, certificate chain and private key generated by Let's Encrypt are still in the same format as before.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a solution at the end?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it just suddenly worked again on another day. I still needed to import a completely new certificate instead of updating the old one though.